# Java Collection search for Max Age

Tags: java, collections, iteration

I need to get the max age from a collection that stores their first name, second name and age in one element.
Example:

```
collection[size++] = new Person(fname,lname,age);

//ex: Person("Bob", "Jones", 50);
```

The code i have got so far is to iterate through the collection but i am stuck on how to get the age part of the element.

```
public int maxAge() {
    int mAge = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i == collection.size(); i++) {
        if (collection[i] > mAge) {
            collection[i] = mAge;
        }
    }

    return mAge; 
}
```

`getSize()` gets the collection size.

Comment: as a sidenote, the condition in your loop will make it never loop. To answer your question, call a method `collection[i].getAge()` or acces the class member variable directly `collection[i].age`

Comment: What type of collection it is?

Comment: @elias an array, clearly.

Comment: Now it's clear, but `collection.size()` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please watch your code. Its assigning mAge to collection,ie -1 will be assigned to collection and you are returning mAge whose value will be always -1.

```
 public int maxAge() {
    int mAge = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++) {
     if (collection[i].getAge() > mAge) {
        mAge = collection[i].getAge();
      }
  }

   return mAge; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `Array` with a `getAge()` method on `Person`, you can try this:

```
public int maxAge() {
    int mAge = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i].getAge() > mAge) {
            mAge = collection[i].getAge();
        }
    }

    return mAge; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to assume that? It's an array of ints.

Comment: not according to `collection[size++] = new Person(fname,lname,age);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public int maxAge() {
    int mAge = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i].getAge() > mAge) {
            mAge = collection[i].getAge();
        }
    }
    return mAge; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depend of the type of object inside collection, assuming is collection of Person:

public int maxAge() {

```
int mAge = -1;
for (Person person: collection) {
    if (person.getAge() > mAge) {
        mAge=person.getAge();
    }
}

return mAge;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To get the person element with max age :

```
Person personWithMaxAge = Collections.max( collection, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare( Person first, Person second) {
        if ( first.getAge() > second.getAge() )
            return 1;
        else if (first.getAge() < second.getAge() )
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

and then `int maxAge = personWithMaxAge.getAge();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8:

```
Optional<Person> person = collection.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge));
```

The type is an optional because the collection might be empty.

now you can use it this way:

```
person.ifPresent(p -> {
    // place your code here
    // System.out.println(p.getAge());
});
```